# Get newest object of each subset

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an app based on [mongodb](http://mongodb.org/) and [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/). One of my schemas has the following form:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name: { type: String },
    timestamp: { type: Number, default: Date.now },
    // further properties
});
schema.index({ name: 1, timestamp: -1 });
```

I'd like to retrieve the newest object (i.e., largest `timestamp`) for a set of `name`-strings.

E.g., consider the set of names `['a','b']`. How do I query the database such that I get returned a collection of objects that contains both, the newest entry where `id=='a'`, and the newest entry where `id=='b'`?

[**Update**: The idea is to avoid having to query the database multiple times (i.e. once for each name).]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How do I query the database such that I get returned a collection of objects that contains the newest where id=='a'"

`db.collection.find({ name : 'a' }).sort({ timestamp : -1 })`

"and the newest entry where id=='b'?"

`db.collection.find({ name : 'b' }).sort({ timestamp : -1 }).limit(1)`